# Ubuntu 18.04 not showing thumbnails for audio and pdf files

Tags: thumbnails

I chose minimum installation at the beginning and after that I have installed ffmpeg Thumbnailer and tried `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.cache/thumbnails` and clearing the thumbnails folder but still thumbnails not visible.